# Quantum Nuclear Corrections

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, nuclear-physics, density-functional-theory

I am interested in calculating quantum nuclear corrections to energy profiles or free energy profiles. For example, say I perform a DFT simulation for some molecules, and I the energetic profile in terms of the position of a hydrogen atom. Now, I would like to understand how much would treating the proton quantum-mechanically change the result. Two possibilities are Path Integral Molecular Dynamics and Multi-component DFT. But what be do, just knowing the energetic profiles and the temperature, to estimate the impact of this effects?

So far, I am trying two things: 
1) Employ the Wigner quasi-probability function, and that's why I asked [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/444205/negative-probabilities-with-wigner-quasi-probability-distributions), because I have several problems with this approach.
2) Perform some WKB calculations, although it is hard to understand how the temperature comes into play here and it is so simple and easy that probably I am missing a lot of things with this approach.

What else can be done? Without having to do Multi-component DFT, which of course is extremely costful, what ideas are out there to at least estimate the nuclear quantum effects?  Possible nuclear quantum effects include changes in mean values of bond-lenghts, changes in the probability densities, in Free Energy barriers,...

Comment: Keep in mind that DFT does not take into account correlation between electrons/particles. This becomes a problem when you have 2 or more particles, e.g. the Helium atoms with 2 electrons or molecules with 2 or more centres.

Comment: 1 year is long to not get an answer, you can copy and paste here: https://materials.stackexchange.com now that Materials.SE is live.